# mysql8 nearest place using radius filter

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

First of all, I am using mysql8.
I have a table that store states of my country.
My table ddl is:

```
CREATE TABLE state_v2(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    uf_code INT NULL,
    uf VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    latitude FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    longitude FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    `country` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    coord POINT SRID 4326 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    unique (country, uf_code),
    unique (latitude, longitude),
    index (uf_code)
);

ALTER TABLE state_v2 ADD SPATIAL INDEX(coord);
```

The user choose a place and I use this place as reference to find the nearest state less then 100km. (the parameter is a correct point).

I am using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
    sv.*,
    ST_distance_sphere(
        $param, 
        sv.coord) as distance
    FROM state_v2 sv 
    WHERE  ST_distance_sphere(
        $param, 
        sv.coord) < 100000
) as temp
order by temp.distance;
```

1 - Is it correct this query? I am worried about the performance of using like that, it is using full table scan.

2 - Is it correct the created indexes?

Comment: You could introduce a bounding into your where condition, in order to improve performance